# Ubuntu Software results not suggested as search location for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-center, search

In 3 separate Ubuntu 20.04 installs, I've noticed when I do a search (after pressing the super button) suggestions from `Ubuntu Software` are no longer showing. After some reasearch, I found that what gets suggested is determined by what's selected in `search Locations` (To get there you go from `Settings > Search`

I appreciate those results, but haven't seen anyone else complain that they're missing. For example, in my Ubuntu 19, software suggestions are clearly present:
[image]

However in Ubuntu 20, it's missing:
[image]

I can't see an option anywhere to add it back. I'm hoping someone else knows how to add it back in, or is a command line guru with these sorts of settings